# AT Command for Searching Signal Quality (Not Strength)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, at-command

I am trying to make an application that can measure Signal, Operator SIM, APN, and other from modem via SerialPort. I want to get the signal quality (Not Strength) such as UMTS, HSPA, HSDPA, or other. Anyone Knows?

If possible, could you also tell me another AT Command that can be used on this kind of application?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no *easy* way to get the signal quality or singal-to-noise ratio for all techonolgies. Manufacturers have it and android has it but it's not available to the apps. The closest AT command is `AT+CSQ` but it only gives you signal level, not quality.

You can get those values for LTE via reflection. Here is an open source example: https://github.com/Tombarr/Signal-Strength-Detector

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I haven't found any other helpful answers, so maybe this could help someone.

There is no standard AT command to get all the parameters needed to evaluate network signal quality, for the 2G the command `AT+CSQ` can be enough, otherwise, depending on the module and firmware, you may have access to proprietary commands that allow you to do this.

For example, in some Quectel modules it is possible to use the `AT+QENG` (or `AT+CESQ` in others Quectel modules) command to obtain quality parameters useful for each technology (such as Ecio, Rsrp, Rsrq, Rsrc etc), on Telit modules there is the `AT#MONI` command and some Gemalto modules Cinterion have commands like `AT^SMONI`.

I suggest for anyone who need something similar to download the AT Command set of the module you have and search for something like "serving cell" or "monitoring" or directly by one of the signal quality parameters (Ecio, Rsrp, Rsrq, Rsrc etc).

Answer (score -1):

AT+CREG has a parameter that gives some indication of the current access technology.
It is documented in section 7.2 of the standard AT command reference, [TS 27.007.](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm)

+CREG:  ,< stat>[,[< lac>],[< ci>],[< AcT>][,< cause_type>,< reject_cause>]]

The parameter "AcT" has the following values:

0   GSM
1   GSM Compact
2   UTRAN (= UMTS)
3   GSM w/EGPRS
4   UTRAN w/HSDPA
5   UTRAN w/HSUPA
6   UTRAN w/HSDPA and HSUPA
7   E-UTRAN (= LTE)

Comment: This does not answer the question (signal quality)

Comment: @brunorey The questioner gives UMTS, HSPA etc as examples of the data that he wants to get, which is pretty clear.  I agree, signal quality is something else - however, people often use the wrong word, especially when English is not their native language.  At the end of the day, it is people's own responsibility to write their questions in clear and unambiguous language.